# ServiceStack.OrmLite nolock hint in SQL Server

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have been reviewing the `ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer` library and it works very well but we were looking at the SQL generated and we wanted to add a nolock hint to our select statements but could not find a any documentation around this?

**Current:**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT "GroupID", "Name", "ShortName", "GroupTypeID", "ParentGroupId" FROM "Group" WHERE "GroupID" = @GroupID',
                   N'@GroupID int', @GroupID = 5543
```

**Would like:**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT "GroupID", "Name", "ShortName", "GroupTypeID", "ParentGroupId" FROM "Group" **WITH (NOLOCK)** WHERE "GroupID" = @GroupID',
                   N'@GroupID int', @GroupID = 5543
```

Any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My preference is to wrap the database call in a system transaction, rather than trying to embed a SQL Server hint into the query.

```
using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{
    using (var tran = db.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
    {
        return db.Select<Group>();
    }
}
```